# 18.04 everytime I try to open something from settings gnome crashes

Tags: gnome, crash, settings

I have a clean and up to date 18.04 install. Everything was.ok for the first boot but after subsequent gnome will crash (black screen and takes me back to the login) if I try to open anything from settings such as network or screenconfig.

Any ideas on where to start?

Amd r7 1700
Asus x370-i
NVIDIA 1080ti
16gb mem.

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Have you installed any GNOME extensions? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this was an addon - disabling gtile allowed me to access the settings.

Comment: I've uninstalled all Gnome Extensions, and still have the issue. Is that what you mean by an "addon"?